# Send E-Mail after Checkout in WooCommerce

Tags: php, html, wordpress, email, woocommerce

i want to add a code which send the email "WC_Email_Customer_On_Hold_Order" after a customer give up his order with the payment method "A" (as example).

But i dont know where to add the code.
Somebody can help?

Comment: have you want an email when WC_Email_Customer_On_Hold_Order  status is on hold?

Answer (score 0):

I know two ways to do that:
Add to functions.php or create a plugin to add your own codes.

Whathever, you may use something like this in any of them:

```php
<?php
function send_email_after_checkout() {
    // Getting current user's email
    global $current_user;
    $to = $current_user -> user_email;

    // Send the email
    $subject = 'Email Subject';
    $body = 'The email body content';
    $headers = array('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8','From: My Site Name <yoursiteemail@domain.com>');
    wp_mail( $to, $subject, $body, $headers );
}
add_action('woocommerce_thankyou', 'send_email_after_checkout')
```

You may have to find another hook, but I think that 'woocommerce_thankyou' will do what you want.